# Why is the USD/HKD is not moving normally?

Tags: foreign-exchange, usd-us-dollar

I know that the RMB is pegged against the USD (and other currencies?), but why is the USD and HKD are not moving as I would expect from other currency pairs? Below is the USDHKD pair on the daily chart, and its pretty much either 7.5 or 7.85. Why? What are the mechanics behind it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

HKD is pegged to USD in the 7.75-7.85 band. What you're observing is by design and is enforced by the Hong Kong central bank. See [here](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-07-31/what-the-hong-kong-dollar-peg-is-and-why-it-matters-quicktake) or [here](https://www.oanda.com/us-en/trading/instruments/usd-hkd/).